# Updating multiple records with context, ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I want to find everything with a certain matching variable, and then update that variable.

Updating that exact variable for every record that was found.

I know context is used to query the database.

How could I do this?

Its not working:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout()
    {
        IEnumerable<Orders> orders = _ocontext.GetAllOrders();
        var movingcart = orders.Where(p => p.Cart == 1);
        foreach (var item in movingcart)
        {
            item.Cart++;
        }
        _context.Update(movingcart);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return View();
    }
```

EDIT::::
I FIGURED IT OUT!:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout()
    {
        var Temp = (from d in _context.Orders
                       where d.Cart == 1
                       select d).Single();
        Temp.Cart++;
        _context.Update(Temp);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: are you getting an error? how does it "not work"?

Comment: if you figure it out, you can post your edited part as the answer, or delete this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed this part where you said "I want to find everything with a certain matching variable, and then update that variable."

To do that, you could do this:

```
var cartItems = _context.Orders.Where(x => x.Cart == 1).ToList();
foreach (var item in cartItems)
{
    item.Cart++;
    _context.Update(item);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer if it's what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout()
{
    var temp= _context.Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Cart == 1);

    temp.Cart++;
    _context.Update(temp);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return View();
}
```